# JavaScript getElementById not working for table

Tags: javascript, button, element, getelementbyid

I have a page with many elements, some are buttons, and some are tables. I need a way of getting the name of these elements, using the same code.

I tried using

```
document.getElementById('theid');
```

and it worked for the buttons, but not for the table. Why not? How can I get the table's and the button's name **using the same code?**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SNYSP/)

Comment: [`name` is not a "designed" attribute for `<table>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes). You can use [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute), or [`data-*` attributes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SNYSP/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Passerby

The code I need to use is

```
document.getElementById('obj1').getAttribute('name');
```

This works for both buttons and tables.